# Using Immutable js, is there a better way to update the value of this array in an immutable object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, immutable.js

So in my react redux project I am updating an array in my state like this:

```
this.setState(fromJS(this.state).set(e.target.id, fromJS(this.state).get(e.target.id).push(e.target.value)).toJS());
```

So just to briefly break it down I am taking a plain js state object turning it immutable then setting the chosen value with a new immutable copy of the array with a new value pushed in.

This seemed to me the only way to do this while making sure I treated the state as an immutable value. I was thinking I can do this:

```
this.setState(fromJS(this.state).set(e.target.id, this.state[e.target.id].push(e.target.value)).toJS());
```

The above I assume mutates the original state so I figured I shouldn't use it. Is the method I choose first the most effective way of making sure everything is immutable? I feel like going in and creating a new object again just to get a new array value seems overly complicated so I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Again my main focus is on this line: `.set(e.target.id, fromJS(this.state).get(e.target.id).push(e.target.value)` where I create an immutable object twice

Comment: Aren't you missing the point of immutable data? You're currently just using Immutable.js to do _very_ fancy deep cloning of your object.

Comment: I guess? Can you explain what you mean? Isn't what I am doing above making sure that I am setting my state to a new object rather then mutating the original? Genuinely curious because honestly this is all new to me and i'd be the last to say I know what the hell I am doing.

Comment: Are the values in your state plain objects/arrays or are they Immutable.Map/List etc.? If they are, then you don't have to make sure you're not mutating the original, because you **can't**.

Comment: Oh I am keeping them as plain objects when using them in the react state, I am using immutable anytime I need to change a value just so I can keep from mutating the original keeping in principle with what i thought the point was. I know I can do that without immutable, but immutable seems to make it easier.

Comment: is keeping them as plain objects a bad idea? I just find it easier to work with on the frontend that way. But i didn't really put much thought into it

Comment: and also to your point even if I kept them as immutable maps/lists, would the way I created a new copy be correct? Or is there a better way to update the value of the array in the immutable map? not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: Let's say `this.state.foo` is an `Immutable.List`, then you simply do `this.setState({foo: this.state.foo.push(e.target.value)})`. Because every mutation (e.g. `push`) returns a new object.

Comment: I see your point. So it would be easier for me to keep the state immutable rather then switch to a plain object, unless something needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `List` structure, docs here :
https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List

It has a `push` operation.
So if you have `this.state` containing an array called `rayy` (`this.state.rayy`), hypothetically you could say:

```
this.setState({ rayy: this.state.rayy.push(e.target.value)})
```

That's not going to mutate the original it will just return a new copy and assign it to `rayy`.

Remember there are two distinct `state`s when working with React together with Redux.  There is the Redux `state` store which transcends any particular component and should be accessible from anywhere, and then there is the `state` specific to individual Components.  I use Immutable with Redux but in the components the `state` is not immutable.  So:

```
[...][coffeescript here]
# components' state (not immutable)
getInitialState: ->
    some_ui_thing: 42
    another_ui_thing: 43

# for Redux's connect: (Redux's state is immutable, transition it to JS for props & render stuff
mapStateToProps: (state) ->
    state.toJS()
```

Now inside my components when I call `@setState` it's just plain mutable JS, which isn't any kind of issue because these vars are private to the component, and typically relate only to transient UI stuff, so the typical reasons for using Immutables arent compelling.

On the other hand in my reducers (Redux), I might have a function :

```
do_something = (state, action) ->
    state = state.setIn ['rayy'], state.rayy.push(action.payload.whatever)
    state
```

I could make it more explicit:

```
do_something = (state, action) ->
    some_list = state.getIn ['rayy']
    some_list = some_list.push action.payload.whatever
    state = state.setIn ['rayy'], some_list
    return state
```

Or more terse:

```
do_something = (state, action) ->
    state.setIn ['rayy'], state.rayy.push(action.payload.whatever)
```

That last (terse) version is possible in coffeescript because it has implicit return.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use immutable.js, you should use it throughout your application, because calling fromJS() and toJS() is bad for performance and require tedious syntax as in your example.

If you like to keep your state as plain JS objects, you should use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) or other libraries such as [immutable-assign](https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign) created by me. Example usage:

```js
var newState = iassign(this.state, 
    function(state, context) { return state[context.id]; },
    function(prop) { prop.push(e.target.value); return prop; },
    { id: e.target.id }
)
this.setState(newState);

// The first parameter is a function that return the property you need 
// to modify in your state. This function must be **pure function**, 
// therefore "id" need to be passed in via the context parameter. 
// 
// The second parameter is a function that modify selected property of your 
// state, it doesn't need to be pure, therefore you can access 
// "e.target.value" directly
//
// The third parameter is the context used in the first function (pure function)
```